# autoclose for alerts angular SPA

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application

I use [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/06/25/angular-2-4-alert-toaster-notifications) article to create app notifications. I'd like to add autoclose alerts but have no idea how to do it. When I try to add timeout in Alert constructor object it doesn't work. Perhaps some of you know how to check trigger timeouts for each alert object in AlertComponent?

Comment: This might not answer your question. But I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster to create alerts. this package is really good and easy to use

Comment: Thank you for tip, I solved it adding line
`   setTimeout(() => {  this.alerts = this.alerts.filter(x => x !== alert);             }, alert.timeout);`
in alertcomponent init and field timeout in model